# Magento 2: Adding custom attributes to pages in the front end

Tags: product-attribute, theme, magento2.2.3

I've added a custom attribute in the Magento 2 back end called preorder and preordernote, then in my custom theme I have created an override to display `Preorder` instead of `Add to Cart` in the product view, as well as the preorder note.

The override is in the following structure:
`Magento_Catalog > templates > product > view > addtocart.phtml.`

I will also be modifying the catalog view, and cart page to include the appropriate pre order messages when a product has the preorder attribute set to 'yes'.

While this is working, I am confused as to if I have used the correct method or not. Is there a recommended way to do this type of customization?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To call attributes that you have created try below code:

```
<?php
    $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
    $product = $objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\Registry')->registry('current_product');//get current product
    $demo = $product->getResource()->getAttribute('your_attribute_code')->getFrontend()->getValue($product);
?>
```

Now you can call this variable `$demo` anywhere you like. like below:

```
<?php echo $demo; ?>
```